# Vertical spacing between numerator and division symbol in \dfrac

Tags: spacing, fractions

How can I fix the vertical spacing between the numerator and the division symbol when entering fractions.

Eg. in the following code, the spacing between `a` and the division symbol is greater than one between `b` and the next (lower) division symbol.

```
\[ x = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c} \]
```

Comment: First of all, stacking fractions is not a recommended practice. You can use `\mathstrut` in the denominator of the inner fraction, so it will be raised a bit.

Comment: The `a` in the numerator is higher because you might have something like `\[\frac{a}{2}\frac{f}{4}\]`.

Comment: @egreg I was trying to write `\[ \phi = \frac{\dfrac{\text{fuel}}{\text{oxidizer}}} {\left(\dfrac{\text{fuel}}{\text{oxidizer}}\right)_{\text{st}}} \]`. I could so something like `\[ \phi = \frac{\text{fuel}/\text{oxidizer}} {(\text{fuel}/\text{oxidizer})_{\text{st}}} \]` but found the former one easier to read. Later on I try to substitute in the numbers which are in the `(a/b)/c` form.  Also `mathstrut` worked `\[ x = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{\mathstrut{b}}}{c} \]`.

Comment: You might try to use `\text{\raisebox{-.4ex}{fuel}}` if you really like to reduce the vertical space.

Comment: Following egreg's suggestion I found a [document](http://www.duke.edu/~hg9/ctex/Math.pdf) which talks about number of recommended practices. Others may find it useful.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Playing with math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ x
  = \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}
  = \dfrac{\frac{\textstyle a}{\textstyle b}}{c}
  = \dfrac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}
  \equiv \dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{c}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]