# How can I configure more space around horizontal line in frac?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
    $\frac{\mbox{Time}}{\mbox{h}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it just me or is the h almost colliding with the horizontal line? I am guessing the spacing is optimised for the math italics(?) but can something be done about it?

---

**Edit**: Seem there are some considerations as to wether the use case is relevant. I want to use it as a table header but perhaps there is a better way to do that as well? Here is a somewhat less minimalistic example to strengthen the validity of the question:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        Foo & $\frac{\mbox{Time}}{\mbox{h}}$ \\
        \midrule
        Bar  & 2.5 \\
        Buzz & 3.0 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\strut`; but probably `\dfrac{\text{Time}}{\text{h}}` (requires `amsmath` and should be used only in display math) already gives a better result.

Comment: Does this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72822/31058) help?

Comment: Use the slashed form.

Comment: Thing is, this a table and horizontal space is worth it's weight in gold... :)

Comment: `$T/h$` is less wide.

Comment: True, but then I would have to define T. I don't know actually...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a good example. If you use it inline, the result will be awful; see the following example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
Here is some text with inside it a fraction; I add some text
before the fraction so it will appear in the middle of the
paragraph. Probably we do now and the fraction is
$\frac{\mbox{Time}}{\mbox{h}}$
hereby shown. Extra text is added after the fraction in
order to show how amazingly awful the result is.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem doesn't show when you properly display the fraction:

```
On the other hand, if the fraction appears displayed, again
after some text for getting at least two lines
\[
\frac{\mbox{Time}}{\mbox{h}}
\]
the result will not show the problem, which is due to the
fact that \TeX{} expects script size material when typesetting
an inline fraction.
```

[image]

If you want the fraction inline, use the slashed form together with `\text` and `amsmath`:

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
```

A text fraction can now be

```
 $a+\text{Time}/\text{h}=42$
```

while in displays you can still say

```
\frac{\text{Time}}{\text{h}}
```

But using “word fractions” is not very good style, in my opinion. Using a properly defined symbol will give the fraction its real mathematical sense.

Comment: The `$\frac{\text{Time}}{\text{h}}$` does not look too bad I think. I am almost considering `$\frac{\mbox{Time}}{\text{h}}$` as well...

Comment: @jonalv We have different tastes, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the size decreases in the numerator and denominator, but `\mbox` prevents this. `\text` from package `amstext` or `amsmath` (the latter loads the former):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amstext}% or amsmath
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    $\frac{\mbox{Time}}{\mbox{h}}$ vs.
    $\frac{\text{Time}}{\text{h}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]